# Do something beside load table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

i have a datatable which i'm loading via Ajax.
in the server side i'm prepering the data for the table and prepare another data for another thing 
i want, beside the table loading, to do another thing with  the other data i've prepared
so i added to my ajax code a success event, but it replace the table loading and i only can do the other thing
i can't separate between the table loading  and the other thing because they are connected, meanning the other thing is influenced by the table loading(changes)

i tried also fnDrawCallback but i don't know how to pass the data of the other thing
Here's the Ajax code with success event:

```
"ajax": {
        "url": "/Entreaties/GetEntreaties",
        "data": function (d) { 
            d.status = 0;
            d.firstLoad = firstLoad;                
            d.jAdvanceSearch = JSON.stringify(new AdvanceSearch());
            d.freeText = $("#table_filter input").val();
        },
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.contactWaySum, function (key, value) {
                alert(key + ": " + value.ContactWay);
            });                
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    },
```

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you were using the built in DataTable ajax but stopped because you wanted to do several things at once. If so, go back to using the DataTable ajax and used the dataFilter function to separate them out and apply them.

Here is an example:

```
// If your server side sends back somehting that looks like this for the data table (this is what it is expecting)

            {draw:1, recordTotal:20, recordsFilter:20, data:dataSet }

            // adjust your json to look like 


            // If the json object return looks like what the 
           { dataTableData:{draw:1, recordTotal:20, recordsFilter:20, data:dataSet }, otherStuffData: otherData}

           $("#sometable").DataTable({
               // other data table stuff left out to save space
               "serverSide": true,
               "ajax": {
                   "url": "you url" ,
                   "data": function (ssp) {
                       // Do the stuff you need to to get your paramerters ready
                       // server side parameters (ssp) are documented at http://datatables.net/manual/server-side
                       // in addition to the ssp parameters, the name of the column is pulled from the table header column


                       return ssp;

                   },
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   error: function (a, b, c, d) { debugger; },
                   dataFilter: function (data) {

                       // call function or what ever you need to do with the other data here

                       doOtherStuff(data.otherStuffData);

                       // the web method returns the data in a wrapper 
                       // so it has to be pulled out and put in the 
                       // form that DataTables is expecting.

                       //return just the datatable data here
                       return JSON.stringify( data.dataTableData);
                   }
               }
           });
```